# How to create a simulated Forget Password feature in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I am currently learning Android programming using Android Studios and have come to a halt with my project.

I am making a simple password maanger for myself and was thinking about a feature where i can reset my master password.

My first idea was to use the email service to send an OTP to myself but realize that it requires me to setup an SMTP server to do that and to authenticate with my local app.

I tried reading up on Google's Authenticator but it is getting nowhere as all i got from that is that i have to set up with Google's api which is a nightmare.

How do i make it so that i can create a simulated function where i send 2fa to myself and use that as a master password recovery tool?

Any ideas would be deeply appreciated.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do that at all.  Let's say that I stole your phone and tried to use the password manager.  So I hit the reset password button.  Your app sends an email to the user as 2fa.  What app is everyone on their phone logged into?  Their email.  So if I have your phone, I'll simply open your email app, get the 2fa code, and enter it.  You have added zero security with this feature, unless you find a user who actually requires a password every time they log into their email app (do they even make email apps like that?  I don't think gmail has a mode for it).

Consider biometrics instead.  While I do not like relying solely on biometrics (fingerprints can easily be gathered and faked), it's a lot better than email verification.